# SQL - Update multiple rows in table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update multiple rows in a table, however I cannot get it working to where it updates all rows at once. I am very lost on how I can achieve this.

```
UPDATE ENROLMENT
INNER JOIN STUDENT ON ENROLMENT.REGNUM = STUDENT.REGNUM
INNER JOIN TOPIC ON ENROLMENT.TOPIC_NUMBER = TOPIC.TOPIC_NUMBER
SET GRADE='87' WHERE FAMILY_NAME='SMITH' and TOPIC_NAME='Internet Computing'
SET GRADE='84' WHERE FAMILY_NAME='SMITH' and TOPIC_NAME='Programming Language Concepts'
SET GRADE='60' WHERE FAMILY_NAME='BLOGGS' and TOPIC_NAME='Computer Networks'
SET GRADE='55' WHERE FAMILY_NAME='BLOGGS' and TOPIC_NAME='Internet Computing'
SET GRADE='72' WHERE FAMILY_NAME='BLOGGS' and TOPIC_NAME='Programming Language Concepts'
SET GRADE='63' WHERE FAMILY_NAME='BLACK' and TOPIC_NAME='Internet Computing';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use case-when in the update set part as below, note that you can provide a `else` condition at the end so that when no condition is matched you can still update with some value. Also its better to specify the `aliasname.columnname` in the set and case when column names for better readability and more importantly to avoid ambiguity.

```
UPDATE ENROLMENT
INNER JOIN STUDENT ON ENROLMENT.REGNUM = STUDENT.REGNUM
INNER JOIN TOPIC ON ENROLMENT.TOPIC_NUMBER = TOPIC.TOPIC_NUMBER
set GRADE = 
case 
 when FAMILY_NAME='SMITH' and TOPIC_NAME='Internet Computing' then 87
 when FAMILY_NAME='SMITH' and TOPIC_NAME='Programming Language Concepts' then 84
 when FAMILY_NAME='BLOGGS' and TOPIC_NAME='Computer Networks' then 60
 when FAMILY_NAME='BLOGGS' and TOPIC_NAME='Internet Computing' then 55
 when FAMILY_NAME='BLOGGS' and TOPIC_NAME='Programming Language Concepts' then 72
 when FAMILY_NAME='BLACK' and TOPIC_NAME='Internet Computing' then 63
end;
```

Here is using alias

```
UPDATE ENROLMENT e
INNER JOIN STUDENT s ON e.REGNUM = s.REGNUM
INNER JOIN TOPIC t ON e.TOPIC_NUMBER = t.TOPIC_NUMBER
set e.GRADE = 
case 
 when s.FAMILY_NAME='SMITH' and t.TOPIC_NAME='Internet Computing' then 87
 when s.FAMILY_NAME='SMITH' and t.TOPIC_NAME='Programming Language Concepts' then 84
 when s.FAMILY_NAME='BLOGGS' and t.TOPIC_NAME='Computer Networks' then 60
 when s.FAMILY_NAME='BLOGGS' and t.TOPIC_NAME='Internet Computing' then 55
 when s.FAMILY_NAME='BLOGGS' and t.TOPIC_NAME='Programming Language Concepts' then 72
 when s.FAMILY_NAME='BLACK' and t.TOPIC_NAME='Internet Computing' then 63
end;
```